# Using express with Karma to test ember app kit app

Tags: ember.js, karma-runner, ember-app-kit

I've just downloaded and installed ember app kit. I've got it running and am using express to fake a backend by following the [included directions](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/tree/master/api-stub).

I've also installed Karma and am attempting to run the tests with it in conjunction with the express backend. I don't believe the express app is being started though because when i view the output of Karma i see it attempting to perform a GET request and failing.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://1.10.1.10:9876/api/posts/1
```

Json is returned when i hit the development port(8000) though.

How do i tell Karma to start up the express app on port 9876 to test against?

I'm using the karma.conf.js from from the [ember-app-kit-todos repo](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit-todos/blob/master/karma.conf.js)

Here is my Gruntfile.js. I also took bits from the todos repo:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // To support Coffeescript, SASS, LESS and others, just install
  // the appropriate grunt package and it will be automatically included
  // in the build process:
  //
  // * for Coffeescript, run `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-coffee`
  //
  // * for SCSS (without SASS), run `npm install --save-dev grunt-sass`
  // * for SCSS/SASS support (may be slower), run
  //   `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-sass`
  //   This depends on the ruby sass gem, which can be installed with
  //   `gem install sass`
  // * for Compass, run `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-compass`
  //   This depends on the ruby compass gem, which can be installed with
  //   `gem install compass`
  //   You should not install SASS if you have installed Compass.
  //
  // * for LESS, run `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-less`
  //
  // * for Stylus/Nib, `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-stylus`
  //
  // * for Emblem, run the following commands:
  //   `npm uninstall --save-dev grunt-ember-templates`
  //   `npm install --save-dev grunt-emblem`
  //   `bower install emblem.js --save`
  //
  // * For EmberScript, run `npm install --save-dev grunt-ember-script`
  //
  // * for LiveReload, `npm install --save-dev connect-livereload`
  //
  // * for displaying the execution time of the grunt tasks,
  //   `npm install --save-dev time-grunt`
  //
  // * for minimizing the index.html at the end of the dist task
  //   `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-htmlmin`
  //
  // * for minimizing images in the dist task
  //   `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-imagemin`
  //
  // * for using images based CSS sprites (http://youtu.be/xD8DW6IQ6r0)
  //   `npm install --save-dev grunt-fancy-sprites`
  //   `bower install --save fancy-sprites-scss`
  //
  // * for automatically adding CSS vendor prefixes (autoprefixer)
  //   `npm install --save-dev grunt-autoprefixer`
  //

  var Helpers = require('./tasks/helpers'),
      filterAvailable = Helpers.filterAvailableTasks,
      _ = grunt.util._,
      path = require('path');

  Helpers.pkg = require("./package.json");

  if (Helpers.isPackageAvailable("time-grunt")) {
    require("time-grunt")(grunt);
  }

  // Loads task options from `tasks/options/` and `tasks/custom-options`
  // and loads tasks defined in `package.json`
  var config = _.extend({},
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        configPath: path.join(__dirname, 'tasks/options'),
        loadGruntTasks: false,
        init: false
      }),
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, { // Custom options have precedence
        configPath: path.join(__dirname, 'tasks/custom-options'),
        init: false
      })
  );

  grunt.loadTasks('tasks'); // Loads tasks in `tasks/` folder

  config.env = process.env;




  // App Kit's Main Tasks
  // ====================


  // Generate the production version
  // ------------------
  grunt.registerTask('dist', "Build a minified & production-ready version of your app.", [
                     'clean:dist',
                     'build:dist',
                     'copy:assemble',
                     'createDistVersion'
                     ]);


  // Default Task
  // ------------------
  grunt.registerTask('default', "Build (in debug mode) & test your application.", ['test']);


  // Servers
  // -------------------
  grunt.registerTask('server', "Run your server in development mode, auto-rebuilding when files change.", function(proxyMethod) {
    var expressServerTask = 'expressServer:debug';
    if (proxyMethod) {
      expressServerTask += ':' + proxyMethod;
    }

    grunt.task.run(['clean:debug',
                    'build:debug',
                    expressServerTask,
                    'watch'
                    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server:dist', "Build and preview a minified & production-ready version of your app.", [
                     'dist',
                     'expressServer:dist:keepalive'
                     ]);


  // Testing
  // -------
  grunt.registerTask('test', "Run your apps's tests once. Uses Google Chrome by default.", [
                     'clean:debug', 'build:debug', 'karma:test' ]);

  grunt.registerTask('test:ci', "Run your app's tests in PhantomJS. For use in continuous integration (i.e. Travis CI).", [
                     'clean:debug', 'build:debug', 'karma:ci' ]);

  grunt.registerTask('test:browsers', "Run your app's tests in multiple browsers (see tasks/options/testem.js for configuration).", [
                     'clean:debug', 'build:debug', 'karma:browsers' ]);

  grunt.registerTask('test:server', "Start a Karma test server and the standard development server.", function(proxyMethod) {
    var expressServerTask = 'expressServer:debug';
    if (proxyMethod) {
      expressServerTask += ':' + proxyMethod;
    }

    grunt.task.run(['clean:debug',
                    'build:debug',
                    'karma:server',
                    expressServerTask,
                    'addKarmaToWatchTask',
                    'watch'
                    ]);
  });

  // Worker tasks
  // =================================

  grunt.registerTask('build:dist', filterAvailable([
                     'createResultDirectory', // Create directoy beforehand, fixes race condition
                     'fancySprites:create',
                     'concurrent:buildDist', // Executed in parallel, see config below
                     ]));

  grunt.registerTask('build:debug', filterAvailable([
                     'jshint:tooling',
                     'createResultDirectory', // Create directoy beforehand, fixes race condition
                     'fancySprites:create',
                     'concurrent:buildDebug', // Executed in parallel, see config below
                     ]));

  grunt.registerTask('createDistVersion', filterAvailable([
                     'useminPrepare', // Configures concat, cssmin and uglify
                     'concat', // Combines css and javascript files

                     'cssmin', // Minifies css
                     'uglify', // Minifies javascript
                     'imagemin', // Optimizes image compression
                     // 'svgmin',
                     'copy:dist', // Copies files not covered by concat and imagemin

                     'rev', // Appends 8 char hash value to filenames
                     'usemin', // Replaces file references
                     'htmlmin:dist' // Removes comments and whitespace
                     ]));

  // Parallelize most of the build process
  _.merge(config, {
    concurrent: {
      buildDist: [
        "buildTemplates:dist",
        "buildScripts",
        "buildStyles",
        "buildIndexHTML:dist"
      ],
      buildDebug: [
        "buildTemplates:debug",
        "buildScripts",
        "buildStyles",
        "buildIndexHTML:debug"
      ]
    }
  });

  // Templates
  grunt.registerTask('buildTemplates:dist', filterAvailable([
                     'emblem:compile',
                     'emberTemplates:dist'
                     ]));

  grunt.registerTask('buildTemplates:debug', filterAvailable([
                     'emblem:compile',
                     'emberTemplates:debug'
                     ]));

  // Scripts
  grunt.registerTask('buildScripts', filterAvailable([
                     'jshint:app',
                     'jshint:tests',
                     'coffee',
                     'emberscript',
                     'copy:javascriptToTmp',
                     'transpile',
                     'concat_sourcemap'
                     ]));

  // Styles
  grunt.registerTask('buildStyles', filterAvailable([
                     'compass:compile',
                     'sass:compile',
                     'less:compile',
                     'stylus:compile',
                     'copy:cssToResult',
                     'autoprefixer:app'
                     ]));

  // Index HTML
  grunt.registerTask('buildIndexHTML:dist', [
                     'preprocess:indexHTMLDistApp',
                     'preprocess:indexHTMLDistTests'
                     ]);

  grunt.registerTask('buildIndexHTML:debug', [
                     'preprocess:indexHTMLDebugApp',
                     'preprocess:indexHTMLDebugTests'
                     ]);

  // Appends `karma:server:run` to every watch target's tasks array
  grunt.registerTask('addKarmaToWatchTask', function() {
    _.forIn(grunt.config('watch'), function(config, key) {
      if (key === 'options') { return; }
      config.tasks.push('karma:server:run');
      grunt.config('watch.' + key, config);
    });
  });

  grunt.registerTask('createResultDirectory', function() {
    grunt.file.mkdir('tmp/result');
  });

  grunt.initConfig(config);
};
```

I'm very new to EAK and Karma. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the location of the proxyURL in the package.json file, as seen [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/package.json#L5). You'll also need to make sure that the [APIMethod](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/package.json#L4) is set to ['proxy' instead of 'stub'](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/tasks/express-server.js#L32).

To actually have the server startup on a port other than 8000, you need to set an [environment variable](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/tasks/express-server.js#L63) at the time you're running the tests. So, if you invoke grunt like this: `PORT=9876 grunt test` it should start the server on the port you specified.